# Conditional grouping of rows within a dataframe group python

Tags: python-3.x, group-by, pandas-groupby

Current Dataframe:

```
id    string    Result
id1   abc    
id1   kph
id1   dfg       True               
id1   asx
id1   qwe       True
id2   tyu       True
id2   rtg       
id2   mnb       
id2   asd
id3   ash     
id3   lbn       True
```

---

Group by id and join string values till 'Result' is true.

---

Desired Dataframe:

```
ID     String           Result
id1  [abc,kph,dfg]    [ , ,True]
id1  [asx,qwe]        [ ,True]
id2  [tyu]            [True]
id2   [rtg,mnb,asd]   [ , , ]
id3   [ash,lbn]       [ ,True]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that assigns a number to each new row in 'Result' that is True, then backfills between each number, and finally groups by these new group designations:

```
import pandas
import numpy

# Set up dataframe
ids = ['id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2','id3','id3']
strings = ['abc','kph','dfg','asx','qwe','tyu','rtg','mnb','asd','ash','lbn']
results = ['','',True,'',True,True,'','','','',True]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'string':strings, 'Result':results})


def get_first(s):
    return s.to_list()[0]

def group_strings(df):
    
    # Define a range iterator that will produce a new number each time it is called
    # and assign a new number to a row whenever the value of 'Result' is True
    num = iter(range(len(df)))

    df['group'] = df['Result'].apply(lambda x: next(num) if x else np.nan)

    # e.g:
    #     id string Result  group
    # 0  id1    abc           NaN
    # 1  id1    kph           NaN
    # 2  id1    dfg   True    0.0
    # 3  id1    asx           NaN
    # 4  id1    qwe   True    1.0
    
    # Backfill nans in 'group' column
    df['group'] = df['group'].fillna(method='backfill')

    # e.g.:
    #     id string Result  group
    # 0  id1    abc           0.0
    # 1  id1    kph           0.0
    # 2  id1    dfg   True    0.0
    # 3  id1    asx           1.0
    # 4  id1    qwe   True    1.0
    
    # In the case that the last row 'group' value is still a NaN, because
    # the 'Result' didn't end in a 'True', we need to increment the 'group'
    # number and apply to the remaining rows
    if pd.isnull(df['group'].iloc[-1]):
        df['group'] = df['group'].fillna(next(num))

    # Group by 'group' and apply 'id'-level aggregation functions
    df_out = df.groupby('group').agg({'id':get_first, 'string':list, 'Result':list}).reset_index(drop=True)

    return df_out


df.groupby('id').apply(group_strings).reset_index(drop=True)


#   id  string           Result
# 0 id1 [abc, kph, dfg] [, , True]
# 1 id1 [asx, qwe]      [, True]
# 2 id2 [tyu]           [True]
# 3 id2 [rtg, mnb, asd] [, , ]
# 4 id3 [ash, lbn]      [, True]
```

Comment: After backfilling nans in 'group' column, group numbers have been assigned without considering 'id'. When we groupby('group'),  I need string values to combine within 'id'. It is grouping values with combining multiple 'id'.

Comment: Could you please update your question with some varying 'id' values so that I know how your final data frame should look.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to group by 'id' as well.